# How to IsSelected a ComboBoxItem in code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

My `ComboBoxItems` are created in run-time by C# code. I can't figure out how to `IsSelect` a `ComboBoxItems` in code behind so it shows as default when `ComboBox` runs.

Basically I'm trying to convert the 2nd line of the following XAML to C# code

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox1">
    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True"></ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

To C#:

```
comboBox[0].IsSelected = "True" // this doesn't exit..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex.aspx) property

```
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can't access the items of a `ComboBox` through an indexer property as per the code in your question (`comboBox[0]` is invalid). So, you'll need to find the item you want, or alternatively, use the `SelectedIndex` property of the `ComboBox` itself, as suggested in another answer.

Secondly, `IsSelected` is of type `bool`, you therefore need to set it as such:

```
comboBoxItem.IsSelected = true;
```

The string literal of `"True"` is used in XAML as that is the nature of the language, and behind the scenes it uses converters to get the real value of the required type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
((ComboBoxItem)cmb.Items[1]).IsSelected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried ComboBox.SelectedItem? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by using `Items` property of `ComboBox`

```
((ComboBoxItem)*testcombo*.Items[3]).IsSelected = true;
```